# MS Access query execution is very slow for a table with double primary keys

Tags: sql, database, performance, ms-access

I have an MS Access database table which has more than 500000 records in it.

Table structure is like this:

```
| ReportDate (Date/Time) | RiskNumber (Decimal) | CustomerName (String) | RiskAmount (Currency) |
|    24.07.2015    |     1234567891011    |      Donald Duck      |      $987,654.00      |
|    24.07.2015    |     9876543210987    |      Bugs Bunny       |      $456,456.00      |
|       ...        |          ...         |        ...            |         ...           |
|       ...        |          ...         |        ...            |         ...           |
|    23.07.2015    |     1234567891011    |      Donald Duck      |      $987,456.00      |
|    23.07.2015    |     9876543210987    |      Bugs Bunny       |      $456,123.00      |
|       ...        |          ...         |        ...            |         ...           |
|       ...        |          ...         |        ...            |         ...           |
```

the table has two Primary keys which are **ReportDate** and **RiskNumber**.
Both  Primary keys are indexed with duplicates allowed.

Each day, around 2500 entries are added to the table with the corresponding date value.
For a particular day, there is no duplicate RiskNumber.

Every day, using Visual Basic code in Excel, I read today`s values from a big Excel file and insert them into the database table. Before doing that, code checks the yesterday´s RiskAmount value to create log record in another log table.

Database update is initated by a user (who has very basic IT knowledge) using an Interface. He/She selects the source Excel file and the rest is handled by Visual Basic code.

These are the generated queries by Visual Basic:

```
SELECT TOP 1 RiskAmount FROM LoanTable WHERE (RiskNumber=1234567891011 AND ReportDate=#2015-07-23#);
INSERT INTO LoanTable (ReportDate, RiskNumber, CustomerName, RiskAmount) VALUES ('24.07.2015', 1234567891011, 'Donald Duck', 987456)
```

So, the Problem is, select query takes almost 1 sec to be executed, which takes around 40 minutes for the entire table to be updated.

How can I optimize this table and queries to make it faster?

EDIT: Here is the GetCellFromAccess Function of DatabaseUtility class:

```
Function GetCellFromAccess(theCriteriaValue As Variant,  _
                           Optional theCriteriaField As String = "RiskNumber",  _
                           Optional theSelectionField As String = "Nothing") As Variant

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim SqlStr As String
Dim cellValue As Variant

Dim theCriteriaValues As New Collection
Dim theCriteriaFields As New Collection
Dim theSelectionFields As New Collection


If Not pDateString = "Nothing" Then
    theCriteriaValues.Add pDateString
    theCriteriaFields.Add "ReportDate"
End If

theCriteriaValues.Add theCriteriaValue
theCriteriaFields.Add theCriteriaField


If Not theSelectionField = "Nothing" Then
    theSelectionFields.Add theSelectionField
Else
    theSelectionFields.Add currentField
End If

'This is the select query Generator, no Problem here
'Output example: "SELECT TOP 1 RiskAmount FROM LoanTable WHERE (RiskNumber=1234567891011 AND ReportDate=#2015-07-23#);" 

SqlStr = SelectQuery(theCriteriaValues, theCriteriaFields, theSelectionFields, , 1)  

cmd.CommandText = SqlStr
Set rs = cmd.Execute

If rs.EOF = True Then
    cellValue = "NOTINDB"
ElseIf rs.fields(0) = Null Then
    cellValue = ""
Else
    cellValue = rs.fields(0).Value
End If

GetCellFromAccess = cellValue
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
GetCellFromAccess = "Failure"

End Function
```

The slowest part of the code is:

```
Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Comment: It is ReportDate. Sorry about that. I corrected the question.

Comment: It is unclear how large your collections are. Consider flipping the data handling. Begin with Access as central repository and using its VBA and SQL engine, import the Excel data into separate table, validate the temp data, then append to final table.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have two primary keys but just two non-unique index.

To have a primary key, add a field with an *AutoNumber*, or create a compound index of the fields `Date` and `Risknumber` and mark this as *Primary*.

Second, you should be able to attach (link) the Excel sheet as a table in Access and run a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
    LoanTable
    ([Date], RiskNumber, CustomerName, RiskAmount)
SELECT
    [Date], RiskNumber, CustomerName, RiskAmount
FROM 
    LinkedExcelTable
```

just once every day.

Comment: Actually, Primary keys are not necessarily AutoNumber. You can define two different non-unique Primary keys in Access. This is what I have here. Also, all Excel to Access Connection is handled by classes I wrote. Therefore, I dont Need to attach Excel sheet to Access table.

Comment: I know. But you don't get a primary key just because you could create one. If you don't need the easy _AutoNumber_, create a compound unique key. Also, you haven't revealed any of your code, but to run a query as you do now for each and every record to insert, is simply the slowest method of all - which is why you ask for alternatives. You don't need these, of course, if you are happy waiting 40 minutes instead of a minute or so. If so, just close the question.

Comment: Dear Gustav, it is an Excel program with visual Basic in the Background. Total code is around 6000 lines. It has a Dashboard. I try to update database correctly to reduce operational Errors. My source Excel is exported from a core Banking System. It may have countless exceptions, it is not standard. Therefore, I have to process and check each value before inserting into the database table.

Comment: How can we know? No clue or Excel tag is present. Anyway, the method would be to validate first, correct or mark as _Ignore_ where needed, then append in one batch. For this, use DAO and a recordset, not SQL. Further, Access might be a better tool for this ... could probably read the bank data, validate and append in one go.